# Whose avatar was Sri Eknath?

Tags: avatars, bhakti, saint

[Sri Eknath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eknath) was one of the famous saints from the Varkari line of Bhakti tradition.

Whose incarnation was he ?

Comment: haha..avatara series continues..

Comment: Possibly Vishnu if he was. Generally, sant Gyaneshwar is considered as the incarnation of Vishnu. He was the greatest devotee of Krishna.